# Create a count consecutive variable by a group variable

Tags: r

I have data like this:

```
df<-data.frame(one=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7), 
               test=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

I want to sum the number of consecutive 'tests' by variable 'one', but importantly they have to be consecutive. So I'd want:

```
dfwant<-data.frame(one=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7), 
        test=c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
        want=c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

I got pretty close with `rle` but was never able to make the new `want` column.

Comment: nope, ID==5 has only 1 consecutive test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `rleid` from `data.table`, grouped by the run-length-id of 'one', 'test', get the `sum` of 'test' as 'want', grouped by 'one', `mutate` 'want' as the `max` of 'want'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(one, test))%>%
   mutate(want = sum(test)) %>%
   group_by(one) %>%
   mutate(want = max(want)) %>%       
   dplyr::select(-grp)
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   one [7]
#     one  test  want
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     2
# 2     1     1     2
# 3     2     1     1
# 4     2     0     1
# 5     2     1     1
# 6     3     1     2
# 7     3     1     2
# 8     4     1     3
# 9     4     1     3
#10     4     1     3
#11     5     0     1
#12     5     1     1
#13     6     1     1
#14     7     0     0
#15     7     0     0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)[, want := max(tabulate(rleid(test))* test), .(one)]
```

Answer (score 3):

An attempt in base R using `ave`, grouping by the `one` column and a cumulative sum of values that are not equal to 1 in the `test` column:

```
ave(df$test, list(df$one, cumsum(df$test != 1)), FUN=function(x) if(any(x==1)) sum(x) else x )
# [1] 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 0 0
```

A shortening of this  logic, with a hat-tip to @RonakShah is:

```
ave(df$test == 1, df$one, cumsum(df$test != 1), FUN = sum)
```

Comment: @RonakShah - that's much better actually. Have edited in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rle` to obtain the lengths of different runs with `1` and then take the maximum of those lengths

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(one) %>%
    mutate(want = with(rle(test == 1), max(0, lengths[values], na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation to your code sample? This will help other users understand what's going on here.